# Clear Screen comand in R Language

Tags: r

I'm new in R language and now learning with RStudio, sometimes when I do code and my command line in so full with errors, and I want to clear the screen. Like you know when you got really tired of messy screen. What is the command to this, like cls in CMD or CLC in Matlab?

Comment: `Ctrl + L` to clear command-line in RStudio.

Answer (score 8):

`CTRL + L` clears the commandline.

But if you want to do that programmatically, you can "force" it by just writing:

```r
cat("\014")
```

which basically sends `CTRL + L` to the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+L that will solve your query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Ctrl + L : It will clear the console.